Appealing an Australian Visa Refusal (Tourist)
My daughter was refused a tourist visa for reasons that the funds she has in the bank are not sufficient, that the salary she is receiving is not enough and that my daughter might not return to the Philippines after the visit.
Can we use as additional proof of financial capacity an Affidavit of Support and Undertaking from her husband and credit card statement and ownership of a service vehicle to prove that she will be returning home after travel?

Is her husband from the Philippines or from Australia?


Can we use as additional proof of financial capacity an Affidavit of Support and Undertaking from her husband and credit card statement and ownership of a service vehicle to prove that she will be returning home after travel?

Your daughter’s application was refused due to insufficient financial means and insufficient ties to the Philippines. Adequate sponsorship from her husband may be enough to satisfy the first issue, although needing a sponsor inherently weakens an application. It does not address the second.
To demonstrate proof of ties, a visitor would have a compelling reason to return to their country of residence:

Business/Professional Ties (for example, her employment contract and a letter from her employer giving her permission to take paid time off)
Family Ties (dependent children and/or close relatives whose circumstances require the presence of the applicant for day-to-day living)
Community Ties (for example, documentation showing that she is integral to local volunteer or religious organisations)
Financial Assets/Real Estate Ties (for example, ownership of a property)

You may find UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e') helpful, it relates to the UK but covers the same refusal reasons given in your question.

Wouldn’t a service vehicle [whatever precisely is meant by that here] be a financial asset?

@JanusBahsJacquet Well yes, but it would have to be (very) high value to be of any use for a visitor visa application IMHO, and probably not likely to influence the outcome anyway.
